# Why IPython Console in Spyder4 updates constantly when connecting to remote kernel on server?

Tags: python, kernel, ipython, spyder, remote-server

I followed the instructions on the [official Spyder page](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-an-external-kernel) and successfully connected to remote kernel via SSH. However I have a problem in my Ipython Console as it refreshes every 2-3 seconds adding `In [1]:` lines infinitely. I suppose it is refreshing of a state on server, but could someone explain what is this, why this happens and can I turn it off, so that the Console behaves the same as when I work on my local kernel(without infinite adding of empty lines)?

Comment: I think this is due to a flaky internet connection.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba No. Actually, my friend helped me to find out the solution here [https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/10240](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/10240)

Comment: And what's the solution exactly? I mean, there are a lot of comments on that issue.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Oh, sorry, didn't see the comment. The exact answer is this https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/10240#issuecomment-543913159

Comment: Thanks! Could you add that as an answer to your question below? I think it's important for other people to have it as a reference.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Ok, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution could be found here in post of *scott-8*: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/10240#issuecomment-543913159

### The copy of the answer:

Don't know about the issue above, but here is what solved my issue for anyone reading: instead of running `python -m spyder_kernels.console` and connecting to the kernel, quit the kernel after running it. Then restart the kernel with `python -m spyder_kernels.console -f kernel-xxxxx.json`, specifying the file that was just created in the runtime directory, and connect to it. This fixed my problem for some reason.